# How to get result value from WebAPI in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core-webapi

```
public async Task<Customer> GetCustomersAsync(string id)
    {
        var prod = new Customer();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string url = "https://xxxxxx.com/api/Customers/" + id;
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            prod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(content);
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(prod);
    }
```

- Class Customer(Models)

  ```
   public class Customer
   {
    public string CodeRandom { get; set; }
    public string NameUs { get; set; }
   }
  ```

I do make a call to the API to get the results. However I can't get the return result when `.Result`

This is how I do it:

```
var infocustomer = customerRepository.GetCustomersAsync(userrating);
string nameus = infocustomer.Result.NameUs;
```

- When I debug, `nameus` exits by itself. Please give me any solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this

```
string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

do this

```
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

and then just

```
return prod;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it still doesn't seem to work.
'string nameus = infocustomer.Result.NameUs;' -- >' string nameus' still doesn't get results. It doesn't give an error, it just hangs and waits

Comment: see my edit - you should only need to return `prod`.  If you still have problems you need to step through it in the debugger